# Produce a dropdownmenu with a unnormal menu structure in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a Dropdownmenu.This is my structure, as you can see, I'm not working with a list.

[image]

**I prepared the jsfiddle for you:**

https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/

So in the end I would like to have it work like that: When you hover over menu1, the first submenupanel should dropdown with its submenulinks.

I tried something like that until now:

```
 #pnlMenu .menu_link:hover #pnlSubmenu .submenu_link {
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given the rule such that when `#pnlMenu .menu_link:hover`, which is a non-existent item on the view, to display the menu. Also you haven't given the correct `position` value.

And having `#plnSubmenu`, not inside the `.menu_link`, you cannot access with CSS. You definitely need to use `JavaScript` as you have to traverse to top. i.e., from `.menu_link` to its parent `#pnlMenu` and then its sibling, then its child.

If you are interested in a pure CSS menu, you can have this:

```css
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; display: block;}
ul li {display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: relative;}
ul li .sample-menu-placeholder,
ul li input {display: none;}
ul li a {text-decoration: none; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 3px 10px; line-height: 1; color: #333; cursor: pointer;}
ul li a:hover,
ul li input:checked + a {background-color: #999; color: #fff;}
ul li input:checked + a + .sample-menu-placeholder {display: block; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #999; margin: 2px 0 0; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="clear" />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" />
      <a>Item 1</a>
      <span class="sample-menu-placeholder">
        <label for="clear">Close Menu</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" />
      <a>Item 2</a>
      <span class="sample-menu-placeholder">
        <label for="clear">Close Menu</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" />
      <a>Item 3</a>
      <span class="sample-menu-placeholder">
        <label for="clear">Close Menu</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" />
      <a>Item 4</a>
      <span class="sample-menu-placeholder">
        <label for="clear">Close Menu</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" />
      <a>Item 5</a>
      <span class="sample-menu-placeholder">
        <label for="clear">Close Menu</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This could be an extension of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908458/462627).